# Capture stdout from ssh session to local machine

Tags: ssh, io-redirection, file-copy, stdout, expect

I am having to put together a script that will ssh into devices to run a command such as "show running-config" and save the output to a file on my local machine. I have done similar tasks like this right from the command line and have it save the file to my local system. For example,

```
ssh test@192.168.142.15 ls > ls_from_remotes_sys
```

And the file ls_from_remotes_sys is on my local system. However, I will need to script this and the only way I know how to do that is with expect. So I have put together this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh test@192.168.142.15 ls > ls_from_remotes_sys
expect "test@192.168.142.15's password:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

The expect script works but the file gets saved to the remote system, which is not what I want.

Question 1 - Why does the file get saved to the local system from command line and why does it get saved to the remote system with expect?

Question 2 - Is there a way to send the file to my local system? (ssh back is not an option)

I was thinking that maybe instead of redirecting into a file I could just have the script output the command results to my screen. So,

Question 3 - If I do this, how can I capture the stdout on my screen from the remote system and send it to a file on the local system?

Comment: `ssh test@192.168.142.15 'some commands' | tee output_from_remotes_sys`

Comment: Does not work in expect. File gets saved to remote system.

Comment: Then run `ssh` with pulic keys instead of `expect`?

Comment: Not an option. However I did just try the script utility. Run "script /path/to/file". Then invoke expect. Then "exit" to stop script and the output is in /path/to/file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `expect` command you use:

```
spawn ssh test@192.168.142.15 ls > ls_from_remotes_sys
```

This, effectively calls

```
exec("ssh","test@192.168.142.15","ls",">","ls_from_remotes_sys")
```

That means the three parameters (`ls`, `>` and the filename) are sent to the remote system; ie the redirection happens on the remote system.

A *kludge* could be to call it via `sh -c "ssh test@...."`.

Another alternative would be to have the redirection done outside of the `expect` script

e,g: if you called this "get_ls"

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh test@192.168.142.15 ls
expect "test@192.168.142.15's password:"
send "password\r"
interact
```

Then you could do `get_ls > ls_from_remotes_sys`.

Comment: though redirecting the output of expect also gets the `spawn ssh...` and `...password:`in the file

Comment: Tested both and both work. I like the "sh -c" option as it seems to be the cleanest.

Comment: @ilkkachu Good point; you can do `log_user 0` at the beginning and then `log_user 1` before the `interact` to block that from showing.