# use ssh result in local program

Tags: shell-script, ssh, system-calls

I'm trying to run a script on a remote machine with ssh and receive the result,
I tried:

```
 sh -c "ssh 192.168.2.202 /etc/my_script.sh arg1 arg2 > result.txt 2>/dev/null "
```

as suggested in this answer [Redirect stdout over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/redirect-stdout-over-ssh) but if I don't redirect STDERR I get:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Is there a better way ? In the end I need to run ssh from inside a program - by system call and be able to receive the result in a file or a variable
Note: connecting to a uProcessor that has a skinny linux ubunto loaded with dropbear ssh

Comment: no, result.txt is on the local machine i.e. the machine from which i'm running the command @Jesse_b

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `sh -c`?  That isn't suggested at all in your linked question.  I cannot reproduce your results though.  Works fine for me using macos to centos.

Comment: It could be a issue of the host ssh. saw the sh -c solution herehttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297438/capture-stdout-from-ssh-session-to-local-machine?rq=1  @Jesse_b

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run `sh -c pwd` or `sh -c "ssh 192.168.2.202 pwd"` ?

Comment: yes, even if I do `sh -c "ssh...."` I get `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Inappropriate ioctl for device
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Bad address `

Comment: It looks like there's a problem on the remote system that's independent of ssh and redirection. Maybe the home directory or one of its parents on the remote system is denying access to the user. Or one of the mount points on the remote system is broken. Can you login to the remote system interactively without any errors?

Comment: I can log in interactively, but anyhow I think you are correct, it's some issue with the remote system @MarkPlotnick

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
ssh user@host "<cmd> > output.txt 2>/dev/null"
```

I believe the problem you have is the inability to isolate the command sent to the SSH shell vs the parameters interpreted by 'sh -c'.